# socket.io client 's namespace invalid

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-client

I am running on the latest version of socket.io, the server code and client code below works well.

```js
// server
const {Server} = require("socket.io"),
  http = require('http');
const httpserver = http.createServer();
io.on("connection", async (socket) => {
  socket.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('socket disconnect');
  })
});

const io = new Server(httpserver, {
  cors: {origin: "*", methods: ["GET", "POST"],}
});
httpserver.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3001');
});

// client
import {io, Socket} from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io('ws://127.0.0.1:3001', {
  transports: ["websocket"]
});

socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
  console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
});
```

then I tried to work with namespace in socket.io

```js
// server
io.of("device").on("connection", async (socket) => {
  socket.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('socket disconnect');
  })
});

// client
const socket = io('ws://127.0.0.1:3001/device', {
  transports: ["websocket"]
});
```

running the code gives me an error saying
**'connect_error due to Invalid namespace'**'

I can't figure out what goes wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ws://127.0.0.1:3001/device` means you are trying to reach the namespace named '/advice', which does not exist on the server.

I think you are looking for the `path` option instead:

```js
const socket = io("ws://127.0.0.1:3001", {
    path: "/device",
    transports: ["websocket"]
});
```

References:

- https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/
- https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-options/#path
- https://socket.io/docs/v4/namespaces/